# Can we initialize the Dragdealer?

Tags: angularjs, dragdealer-js

I'm working with a Dragdealer to display the avg votes so I want to display the avg in the Dragdealer but I didn't found any way to do this.
Is it possible to initialize the Dragdealeror to set his position.
if no there is any component which can do this?